# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The error "error parsing XML: unbound prefix" shows up on my main layout: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="1" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" style="@style/RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TitleItem">
    <TextView android:ellipsize="3" android:id="@id/action_bar_title" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:singleLine="true" />
    <TextView android:ellipsize="3" android:id="@id/action_bar_subtitle" android:visibility="2" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_subtitle_top_margin_material" android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **1.**  Post xml code here **2.** Now if possible use Android studio

Comment: Agreed with b developer - Google has stopped supporting Eclipse for Android development. You should transition to Android Studio.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="1" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" style="@style/RtlOverlay_Widget_AppCompat_ActionBar_TitleItem">
    <TextView android:ellipsize="3" android:id="@id/action_bar_title" android:layout_width="-2" android:layout_height="-2" android:singleLine="true" />
    
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the `android` XML namespace. Add the following to your root `LinearLayout` element:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```